# Android Layout not displayed or displayed below the previous layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-drawer

I am building an app which is supposed to have an activity with fragments inside.

The overall display works but when I try to show a loading screen, it's never displayed. When I am taping on the top bar, it supposed to display another fragment but this one do not appear. I realize that the new fragment is displayed below the current layout.

here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.HomeScreenActivity">



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/homelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:visibility="gone"
                layout="@layout/layout_loading"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/top_bar_menu"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/loading_car"
                    android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.5"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            style="@style/Widget.Custom.NavigationView"
            android:background="@color/gainsboro_06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_nav_header">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/signout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/denotive_red"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/signout" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/select_vehicle_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>



</layout>
```

the behavior I expect is to be able to load the loading screen and for now, I am using:

```
       homeScreenBinding.loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

and

```
       homeScreenBinding.loading.visibility = View.GONE
```

nothing shows up.

Same for the list I am supposed to display when taping on `toolbarTitle` . I did the code below

```
homeScreenBinding.toolbarTitle.setOnClickListener {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                homeScreenBinding.selectVehicleLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                replaceFragment(VehiclesListFragment(), R.id.select_vehicle_layout)
            }
        }
```

The fragment appears but it's like below the `homelayout`

the replaceFragment is defined as:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, container: Int) {


    val className = fragment.javaClass.name
   // supportFragmentManager
   //     .beginTransaction()
   //     .replace(container, fragment, className)
   //     .addToBackStack(className)
   //     .commit()

    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        replace(container, fragment, className)
        addToBackStack(className)
    }

}
```

I put some logs and I saw that clicks are catch and that we access the fragment. it's like anything which is supposed to be displayed on top of the DrawerLayout or `homeLayout` can't be displayed.

here is the loading layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I feel that the issue is coming from the `DrawerLayout`. When i try to get ride of the `DrawerLayout` for test, the loading layout shows up

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Probably there something in the constraints in the `loading` layout .. could you share it

Comment: @Zain I have added the loading layout

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to show a loading screen, it's never displayed

From the provided XML layouts, the `main_container` is overplayed on top of the loading_screen; i.e. the loading screen won't be seen as it's behind the main container.

To fix this, move the loading screen to be below the `main_container`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.HomeScreenActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/homelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/top_bar_menu"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/loading_car"
                    android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.5"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
                
                
            <include
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:visibility="gone"
                layout="@layout/layout_loading"/>
                

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <!--   Rest of the layout  -->

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</layout>
```

> When I am taping on the top bar, it supposed to display another fragment but this one do not appear. I realize that the new fragment is displayed below the current layout.

The code that is commented out should be working:

```
   // supportFragmentManager
   //     .beginTransaction()
   //     .replace(container, fragment, className)
   //     .addToBackStack(className)
   //     .commit()
```

Instead of the current one.